# Can you install and run apps built on the .NET framework on a Mac?

Tags: .net, macos

I need to use/continue developing a desktop app developed using .NET on my Mac. Is there a .NET framework 4.0 available for Mac? Would this allow running and developing of .NET-based apps on a Mac?

Another option that i am considering is using a windows virtual machine on the Mac.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use a .Net environment [Visual studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/mac/#vs_mac_table), Take a look at the [differences](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/mac/#vs_mac_table) with the PC version.

A lighter editor would be [Visual Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)

Alternatives :

1. Installing the [Mono Project runtime](https://www.mono-project.com) . It allows you to re-compile the code and run it on a Mac, but this requires various alterations to the codebase, as the fuller .Net Framework is not available. (Also, WPF applications aren't supported here either.)
2. Virtual machine ([VMWare Fusion](https://www.vmware.com/ca/products/fusion.html) perhaps)
3. Update your codebase to .Net Core, (before choosing this option take a look at this [migration process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/))

   - [.Net Core 3.1](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0) is an open-source, free and available on Window, MacOs and Linux
   - As of September 14, a ***release candidate <sup>1</sup>*** of [.Net Core 5.0](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0) has been deployed on Window, MacOs and Linux.

[1] : Release candidate (RC) : releases providing early access to complete features. These releases are supported for production use when they have a go-live license

Comment: Not only that, but Visual studio is also available (used to be Xamarind).

Comment: This answer is really old and could do with an update.

Answer (score 29):

- **[.NET Core](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core)** will install and run on macOS - and just about any other desktop OS.
  IDEs are available for the mac, including:

  - [Visual Studio for Mac](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/mac/)
  - [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/download) (free, but not as professional/focused as VS)
  - [JetBrains Rider](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/) (paid)
- **[Mono](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/supported-platforms/macos/)** is a good option that I've used in the past.  But with Core 3.0 out now, I would go that route.

Comment: If you reference .net framework libraries in your .net core console app will this work on Mac or no?

Comment: The question is regarding .net framework, not .net core

Comment: Running a .Net Core app with a form I get the msg “It was not possible to find any compatible framework version’, and provides a link to https://aka.ms.dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App&framework_version=3.1.0&arch=x64&rid=osx.10.15-x64 to install it. This link does not appear to exist – instead I am taken to https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3/1/runtime//utm_source=getdotnetcore$utm_medium=referral.

I have installed the .Net Core SDK  (v 3.1.404) on the Mac but still get the same error.  How can I fix the missing framework problem?

Answer (score 8):

Yes you can!

As of November 2016, Microsoft now has integrated .NET Core in it's [official .NET Site](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#macos)

They even have a new [Visual Studio app](http://code.visualstudio.com/) that runs on [MacOS](http://code.visualstudio.com/docs/?dv=osx)

Comment: A question, do I need to download and install .NET framework separately or it's available with Visual Studio?

Comment: It seems you have to install the .net core first http://code.visualstudio.com/docs/runtimes/dotnet

Comment: Doesn't look like .NET Core is the same as .NET Framework https://www.microsoft.com/net/download

Comment: They are not and some libraries do not exist in .NET Core. It is not a drop in replacement for .NET Framework

Comment: @JonathanWommack Is it at all easy to convert a .NET project into a .NET Core project? Or is it vastly different?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to download the SDK and then you need to run this command. Because by default it does not add the env variable.

if you run this command in the terminal, it will fix your issue

```
ln -s /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet /usr/local/bin/
```

Answer (score -1):

.NetCore is a fine release from Microsoft and Visual Studio's latest version is also available for mac but there is still some limitation. Like for creating GUI based application on .net core you have to write code manually for everything. Like in older version of VS we just drag and drop the things and magic happens. But in VS latest version for mac every code has to be written manually. However you can make web application and console application easily on VS for mac.

Comment: I mean I don't want to be harsh on it, but it's in no way a "fine" release. The limitations really cause you to utilize both mac and pc versions to really optimally utilize. If you are are a hard core .net user, I don't see a way you could use mac only.

Comment: I can see lots of ways you would use mac only.  Maybe you are making an app that would give redundant functionality on windows but fills a missing gap of functionality on mac.  Happens all the time.