# Using .NET 4.x in Unity on a Mac

Tags: c#, .net, macos, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

How can you use .NET 4.x on a **MAC** and use VSCode as the editor!

I have those settings set in unity:

[image]

In VScode I get the following error:

`The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend.
        Failed to load project file '/Data/unity_learn/RIG/Assembly-CSharp.csproj'.
/Data/unity_learn/RIG/Assembly-CSharp.csproj
/Users/doekewartena/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.16.0/.omnisharp/1.32.4/omnisharp/msbuild/15.0/Bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1195,5): Error: The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend.`

I can't find a download for `4.x` version for the mac.

Comment: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/mac/

Comment: unfortunately VS code is very limited support to .Net Framework projects, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47707095/visual-studio-code-for-net-framework) for some workarounds

Answer (score 23):

Omnisharp defaults to using dotnet if it's available, which isn't enough for what you need. To make omnisharp use mono (which comes with the needed profiles), you'll need to:

1. Install mono 5.8 or greater. I recommend installing with homebrew: `brew install mono`
2. In VSCode's user settings file, force omnisharp to use the global mono installation: `"omnisharp.useGlobalMono": "always"` (`auto`

The output in VSCode should show something like

```
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
    Located 2 MSBuild instance(s)
        1: Mono 15.0 - "/usr/local/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin"
        2: StandAlone 15.0 - "/Users/x/vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.17.1/.omnisharp/1.32.8/omnisharp/msbuild/15.0/Bin"

[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
    Registered MSBuild instance: Mono 15.0 - "/usr/local/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin"
```

If it still complains after doing this (if, let's say, it picks the wrong mono installation), you can also force omnisharp to use homebrew's mono by setting

`"omnisharp.monoPath": "/usr/local/"`

or a specific installation of mono with

`"omnisharp.monoPath": "/usr/local/Cellar/mono/5.14.0.177/"`

Comment: "Install mono 5.8 or greater." do you mean 5.18? I could not find anything higher.

Comment: This right here is the answer for all of us! Works even with .NET 7.1.3

Comment: THANK YOU. Installing mono and changing the "omnisharp.useGlobalMono" preference from "auto" to "always" in VIsual Studio Code was the fix I needed.

Comment: This solution also worked for Linux. Thank you!

Comment: this still worked for me on MacOSX and Unity in 2021

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the .NET Core not the .NET Framework, core is only at 2.1

check out this other similar question, unfortunately.

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31864724/can-you-install-and-run-apps-built-on-the-net-framework-on-a-mac)

the first two answers will tell you what you need to know.

Answer (score -1):

go here and download this 
https://www.microsoft.com/net/download

for mac osx 
It may be some environment variable missing too. Try reinstalling.