# How can I deploy .NET Framework application on Mac and Windows both? How to Build Cross-Platform(windows and MacOS) .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have Windows version of .NET Framework desktop application. Now I want to make version available for MacOS as well.

Is there any solution available using C#?

Will .NET Core work for both Windows and MacOs?

Comment: According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31864724/can-you-install-and-run-apps-built-on-the-net-framework-on-a-mac#:~:text=NET%20Core%20will%20install%20and,Visual%20Studio%20for%20Mac), you can run .Net Core apps on both Windows and MacOs. You can follow the instruction [here](https://stackify.com/cross-platform-net-core-apps/#:~:text=NET%20Core%20is%20that%20you,architectures%20like%20x86%20and%20ARM.).

Comment: The official documentation is your friend: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/macos. And no, you cannot run .NET Framework apps on MacOS.

Comment: @LêKiệt  The question is about **.NET Framework** and not about **dotnet core**

Comment: @MarkusMeyer The question clearly states "Will .Net Core work for both Windows and MacOs?", so this question is not about .NET Framework but about what would work in MacOS.

Comment: .NET Core per se - yes, it will run on MacOS. WPF or Windows Forms - even on .NET Core - however will **not** .. See here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-3-and-support-for-windows-desktop-applications/

Comment: Do you mean it is a desktop application on Windows (eg. WinForms/WPF)? If so, it will not run on Linux/MacOS on top of .NET Core. If it is a WinForms app, the .NET Framework build _might_ run on Linux/MacOS using [Mono](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/winforms/) but only if it does not use any Windows API directly.

Comment: @GyörgyKőszeg I have already build application using WinForms C#. I have created exe for window.. Similarly I want to run application on MacOS as well

Answer (score 0):

> I have already build application using WinForms C#. I have created exe for window.. Similarly I want to run application on MacOS as well

You can try [Mono](https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/) then. It has (a rather limited) [WinForms support](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/winforms/getting-started-guide/). But if you never tested it on any other platforms yet, then be prepared for some issues. Among others:

- You will not able to use any WinAPI directly (ie. extern methods to Win32 dlls)
- You might expect some behavioral differences. Some of them affect only particular [distributions](https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/20413).
- Many of these can be handled by special handlings in you code, though. But it means you will need some [`IsWindows`](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.Drawing.Tools/blob/aa7361f8b0514af78b4125d4cca377848d68f5ad/KGySoft.Drawing.ImagingTools/View/Controls/ScalingToolStrip.cs#L125)distinction here and there, just like in [this](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.Drawing.Tools) project of mine.

And do not forget to install [libgdiplus](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/libgdiplus/), which makes possible to use `System.Drawing` on non-Windows platforms, as WinForms is built on GDI+.